# Get indexes of 3 largest values in a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, slice

I have an array in PHP which holds a bunch of unix timestamps.

As a simplified example, here is an array of 10 values.

```
$array = [
  1510790277,
  1586522582,
  1572272336,
  1650049585,
  1591332330,
  1698088238,
  1646561226,
  1639050043,
  1652067570,
  1548161804,
];
```

I need to produce an array containing the indexes of the 3 largest numbers in that array.

From the sample array, I would expect a result of `[5, 8, 3]` -- in that order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to sort the array and maintain index and then use [slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) along with the 4th parameter, again to maintain the index, to grap the top x number of elements you are after, and finally use [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

There may well be a quicker way, but it's just to show there are plenty of PHP array functions to help you achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem with one little exception. The function that gave me the 3 largest values as the first 3 numbers in the new array needs to be arsort, instead of asort

Comment: Ah, glad it helped. Alternatively you could have used array_slice to slice the other end of the array - but it's the same difference really.

Answer (score 1):

Simon posted the simple and probably good-enough performing method.

The other option, only if you have a really large array, is to scan through the array and keep track of the indexes of the three highest values you see. This is O(n), but (especially since its in interpreted PHP code, not a compiled built-in function), probably slower for all but the largest of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

```
function select(list[1..n], k)
     for i from 1 to k
         maxIndex = i
         maxValue = list[i]
         for j from i+1 to n
             if list[j] > maxValue
                 maxIndex = j
                 maxValue = list[j]
         swap list[i] and list[maxIndex]
     return list[k]

newarray[] = select(array, 1);
newarray[] = select(array, 2);
newarray[] = select(array, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the keys of the three latest unix timestamps in the array, do the following:

1. Sort the array of integers in a descending direction while preserving the original keys, then
2. Truncate all elements after the first 3 elements while preserving the original keys, then
3. Access the keys of the reduced array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a7tEb))

```
arsort($array);
var_export(
    array_keys(
        array_slice($array, 0, 3, true)
    )
);
```

---

If seeking a time complexity of O(n) (meaning a single pass over the array), then considerable convolution will be needed. A series of conditions will need to check each value for its potential placement in the result array, then the actual insertion into the result array, then the potential removal of "bumped out" elements. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iluDq))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    if (!$result || $v > $array[$result[0]]) {
        array_unshift($result, $i);
        unset($result[3]);
    } elseif (!isset($result[1]) || $v > $array[$result[1]]) {
        array_splice($result, 1, 0, $i);
        unset($result[3]);
    } elseif (!isset($result[2]) || $v > $array[$result[2]]) {
        $result[2] = $i;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -2):

In PHP code:

```
function threeLargest($array){
 krsort($array, "SORT_NUMERIC");
 $return[0] = $array[0];
 $return[1] = $array[1];
 $return[2] = $array[2];
 return $return;
}
```

Comment: this did not work. For some reason, non of the sorting functions for arrays seem to be working in my debugger...

Comment: Even after removing the quotes around the sorting flag constant, this snippet does not return the required result. https://3v4l.org/7VRCO